# Python multiprocess does not update object attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

Quite new with Python and I am not sure to understand this use case. Why isn't my data updated ? I checked that the object `data` is everywhere the same (same memory location) but its attributes are not updated.

Code sample

```
from multiprocessing import Process


class Data(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.val1 = 0
        self.val2 = 0
        self.val3 = 0
        self.val4 = 0


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def update_val1(self):
        self.data.val1 = 1

    def update_val2(self):
        self.data.val2 = 2

    def update_val3(self):
        self.data.val3 = 3

    def update_val4(self):
        self.data.val3 = 4


data = Data()
test = Test(data)
jobs = []

p = Process(target=test.update_val1)
jobs.append(p)
p.start()

p = Process(target=test.update_val2)
jobs.append(p)
p.start()

p = Process(target=test.update_val3)
jobs.append(p)
p.start()

p = Process(target=test.update_val3)
jobs.append(p)
p.start()

for job in jobs:
    job.join()

print(data.val1)
print(data.val2)
print(data.val3)
print(data.val4)
```

I think this is not a good approach and I better pass `data` object in a queue to share this object between processes is that right ? But the `data` object is the same in each process, not a copy, so I am confused why it does not work.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` object is a copy. Every process has its own memory space independent from any other process, so everything is copied.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes and https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes for how to communicate data across process boundaries.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I break in methods `update_val1` and `update_val2`, the object `data` is the same (same memory block). Is that an issue of my IDE (PyCharm) ?

Comment: @GuillaumeA How can you tell whether it's the same memory block? Forking a new process doesn't change the addresses of anything; the new process is simply a complete clone of the old one. Memory is local to each process.

Comment: Ok, I've used a manager namespace as a shared object to retrieve each process result. I had to slightly modify my class methods, but it works. I was just confused by the PyCharm debugger...